# Check null in C# 6 with default value

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I am using **C# 6** and I have the following:

```
public class Information {
  public String[] Keywords { get; set; }
}

Information information = new Information {
  Keywords = new String[] { "A", "B" };
}

String keywords = String.Join(",", information?.Keywords ?? String.Empty);
```

I am checking if information is null (in my real code it can be). If it is than join a String.Empty since String.Join gives an error when trying to join null. If it is not null then just join information.Keywords.

However, I get this error:

```
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[]' and 'string'
```

I was looking on a few blogs and supposedly this would work.

Am I missing something?

What is the best alternative to do this check and join the string in one line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the types must match on either side of the [?? (null-coalescing)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator you should pass a string array, in this case you could pass an empty string array.

```
String keywords = String.Join(",", information?.Keywords ?? new string[0]);
```

Comment: That fixes it ... I missed the non matching types.

Comment: @Servy I missed understood the error phrase. I interpreted as operand ?? cannot be applied to types String[] and String instead of interpreting as the types did not match. See?

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative would be to check for null **before** joining the strings:

```
var keywords = information?.Keywords == null ? "" : string.Join(",", information.Keywords);
```